# can I give hostname for each container in kubernetes

Tags: docker, jenkins, kubernetes, containers

```
agent {
        kubernetes {
            yaml """
spec:
  
  containers:
  - name: abc
    image: myrepo/abc:v1.0
    tty: true
    command:
     - cat
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "16Gi"
        cpu: "8000m"
      limits:
        memory: "64Gi"
        cpu: "8000m"
    securityContext:
      runAsGroup: 500
      runAsUser: 500
  - name: mssqldb
    image: myrepo/mssql:2019-latest
    tty: true
    readinessProbe:
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      failureThreshold: 10
      periodSeconds: 3
      tcpSocket:
        port: 1433
    securityContext:
      runAsUser: 11001
      runAsGroup: 0
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "4Gi"
        cpu: "4000m"
      limits:
        memory: "8Gi"
        cpu: "8000m"
"""
            defaultContainer 'abc'
            
        }
    }
```

I am running this in my pipeline, but what I am trying to do is to have a hostname for each container, because container to be able to communicate with each other, plus I want to add another container as a client that will try to connect to the server which is the abc container.
when I added hostname before containers part, i get same hostname for all the container which I don't really get, unless it is giving a hostname for the host luanching the containers (ps: when trying the hostname command it gives a random name that changes each time, unless I define the hostname)

Answer (score 0):

Containers in the same pod can use localhost to talk to each other

This is a fixed local address from within the pod, it will not change and does not have to be set

So in your example, the address "localhost:1443" could be used to talk to the container mssqldb from any of the other containers

Comment: what if I want a client server communication? and I'm not sure if there's only one port or more that the client will use to connect to server.
Furthermore, it's not logical to communicate client and server using localhost, I want them to have different IPs at least

Comment: use a service layer https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/